# Using Jquery to replace text in a div when a button is pressed

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how using jquery I can replace text in a div with another piece of text when a button is pressed.

Div:

```
<div id="message">example message</div>
```

Button:

```
<input id="hideshow" type="button" value="here" onclick="replaceWith();">
```

I want to replace "example message" with "test message"

I found this online but it didn't work:

```
$('#notes').on("click", "#hideshow", function(e){
    $("#message").replaceWith("test message");
});
```

Comment: learn events and innerHTML,textContent etc methods of js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this....

    $(document).on("click", "#hideshow", function(e){
    $("#message").text("test message");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [text](http://api.jquery.com/text) instead of replaceWith:

```
$("#message").text("test message");
```

Comment: are you sure about the bound event?

Comment: sorry, could not get you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text()` for the `div` and `val()` for `input`

Answer (score 0):

You must use the text method to change the message:

```
$('#notes').on("click", "#hideshow", function(e){
    $("#message").text("test message");
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfgr0yfb/2/)